# Restriction of homomorphism to finite index subgroup gives finite index subgroup of kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Suppose we have a surjective homomorphism $f:G \to H$ with $H$ a finitely generated free abelian group and that $\ker f$ contains a finite index subgroup $B$. Can we always find a finite index subgroup $A$ of $G$ such that $f$ retstricted to $A$ has kernel $B$?

I have can see that the kernel of $f$ restricted to $A$ equals $\ker f \cap A$, but this does not really help me any further.

**reason why I ask this question**: I am currently writing my masters thesis. A have a statement which says that a given group has a finite index subgroup which has property $\mathcal{P}$. I have shown that the kernel of $f$ has such a finite index subgroup with property $\mathcal{P}$, but the text says that the kernel therefore has property $\mathcal{P}$. I assume that the text implicitly used the above conjecture, by restricting $f$ to the finite index subgroup $A$, and the kernel would then be the group with property $\mathcal{P}$.

I hope this makes any sense...

**EDIT**: on proposal of @stewbasic, I include the proof in which I do not udnerstand a part. The set $PG(F_n)$ denotes the set of polynomially growing outer automorphisms, the set $UPG(F_n)$ the set of unipotent polynomially growing outer automorphism. These are outer automorphisms such that the abelianisation matrix is conjugated to a upper triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal.

> lemma: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a subgroup of $Out(F_n)$ that does not contain a free subgroup of rank $2$. Then there are finite index subgroup $\mathcal{H}_0$ of $\mathcal{H}$, a finitely generated abelian group $A$ and a map $\Phi: \mathcal{H}_0 \to A$ such that $\ker \Phi$ is UPG.
>   Proof:
>   Let $\mathcal{L} = \{ \Lambda_1, \ldots, \Lambda_k\}$ and $\mathcal{H}_0$ as in lemma 7.0.10. Define $\Phi = \sum PF_{\Lambda_i^+}: \mathcal{H}_0\to \mathbb{Z}^k$, where each $PF_{\Lambda_i^+}$ is as in corollary 3.3.1. By corollary 5.7.6. it suffices to show that $\ker \Phi$ is contained in $PG(F_n)$... **(proof then shows that this is true and this is the last part of the proof)**

The proof then continuous to show that the kernel is PG. 
corollary 7.5.6. however states that

> if $\mathcal{O} \in PG(F_n)$ is contained in the kernel of the natural homomorphism
>   $$Out(F_n) \mapsto GL(n, \mathbb{Z}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$$ then $\mathcal{O} \in UPG(F_n)$. In particular, every subgroup of $PG(F_n)$ contains a finite index subgroup in $UPG(F_n)$

and the proof does not show that $\ker \Phi$ is in the kernel of this natural homomorphism.

Comment: The only chance this will work is if you can set $A$ to be the normalizer of $B$. $B$ must be normal in $A$ and you want $A$ as large as possible.

Comment: @Max: it does not seem like this is the case in the paper. anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: So based on your question title, $B$ has finite index in ker $f$, correct?

Comment: It sounds like you want this result in order to complete a proof of some other result. I suggest asking about the latter result directly, in case the omitted steps are not as you assume.

Comment: @AndrewKelley yes, $B$ has finite index in $\ker f$.

Comment: @stewbasic The proof in which I do not understand a part is the conclusion of a paper of 100 pages. I can include the proof, but I am not sure if this would be really helpful...

Comment: @Student Are you already satisfied that $[\mathcal H:\mathcal H_0]<\infty$ and $\ker\Phi\subseteq PG(F_n)$? Then it remains to show $\ker\Phi\subseteq UPG(F_n)$? Perhaps the proof intends to use the first part of the corollary rather than "In particular...". ie it suffices to show $\ker\Phi\subseteq\ker(Out(F_n)\to GL(n,\mathbb Z_3))$.

Comment: @Student actually I think you have given enough information to complete the proof; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $N$ be the set of maps from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z_2$, which forms an Abelian group under the operation of pointwise addition; $(a+b)(n)=a(n)+b(n)$. Now use the action of $\mathbb Z$ on $N$ given by
$$(n\cdot a)(m)=a(m-n)$$
to form the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $G=N\rtimes\mathbb Z$ (recall that $(a,n)(b,m)=(a+n\cdot b,n+m)$). For $n\in\mathbb Z$ consider the homomorphism
$$
  eval_n:N\to\mathbb Z_2,\,a\mapsto a(n),
$$
Let $B=\ker eval_0$. Note that $B$ is normal of finite index in $N$ (indeed $N/B\cong\mathbb Z_2$). Moreover
$$
  eval_n(n\cdot a)=a(0)=eval_0 a,
$$
so $n\cdot B=\ker eval_n$. Thus for $(a,n)\in G$,
$$
  (a,n)B(a,n)^{-1}=\ker eval_n,
$$
so the normalizer of $B$ in $G$ is exactly $N_G(B)=N$.

Finally let $H=G/N$ and $f:G\to H$ be the natural surjection. Note that $H\cong\mathbb Z$ and $\ker f=N$. If such a subgroup $A$ exists, then $A\subseteq N_G(B)=N$. But $N$ does not have finite index in $G$, a contradiction.

---

As for the specific result, the proof can be completed as follows. Let $\Psi:Out(F_n)\to GL(n,\mathbb Z_3)$ denote the map in Corollary 7.5.6. The Corollary states that
$$
  PG(F_n)\cap\ker\Psi\subseteq UPG(F_n).
$$
The proof of the lemma constructs $\mathcal H_0\le\mathcal H$ and $\Phi:\mathcal H_0\to A$ such that $[\mathcal H:\mathcal H_0]<\infty$ and $\ker\Phi\subseteq PG(F_n)$. Now the subgroup $\mathcal H_1=\mathcal H_0\cap\ker\Psi$ has the required properties. Indeed $[\mathcal H_0:\mathcal H_1]<\infty$ since the codomain of $\Psi$ is finite, ensuring $[\mathcal H:\mathcal H_1]<\infty$. Also
$$
  \ker\Phi|_{\mathcal H_1}=\ker\Phi\cap\ker\Psi
    \subseteq PG(F_n)\cap\ker\Psi\subseteq UPG(F_n)
$$
as required.

Comment: In your definition of $eval_n$, did you mean $a \mapsto a(n)$?

Comment: Also, isn't your example basically the same as mine except that you are dealing with the unrestricted wreath product instead of the restricted wreath product?

Comment: @AndrewKelley Thanks for the correction. Yes, it is essentially the same as your answer, which I didn't see until after I wrote mine.

Comment: I'll have to read this carefully when I'm home,but this looks exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is possible that no such finite index subgroup $A$ of $G$ exists.

First, notice the following about any such group $A$. (This is inspired by Max's comment.) Since $B$ will be the kernel of a homomorphism with domain $A$, it must be normal in $A$. Thus $A$ must be contained in $N_G(B)$, the normalizer of $B$. So if $N_G(B)$ does not have finite index in $G$ then neither does $A$, and hence, we will have a counterexample.

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z} = (\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, the lamplighter group. (G is a wreath product, a specific type of semidirect product.) We will represent an element of $G$ as a pair $(g,n)$, where $g \in \mathbb{F}_2[x,x^{-1}]$ is a Laurent polynomial, and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The group operation in $G$ is given by $$(g_1,n)(g_2,m) = (g_1 + x^ng_2, n+m).$$ Let $H = \mathbb{Z}$. Then there is an obvious surjection $f : G \to H$ given by $f((g,n)) = n$. So ker $f$ = $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the following subgroup $B$ of ker $f$: 
$B = \langle x^n | n \neq 0 \rangle$. $B$ is the set of all Laurent polynomials whose coefficient of $x^0$ is 0. So $B$ has index 2 in ker $f$.

Claim: $N_G(B)$ = ker $f$, which has infinite index in $G$.

Proof: We know that ker $f$ = $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ normalizes $B$ because ker $f$ is abelian. Hence
$N_G(B) \supseteq$ ker $f$. To show the other containment, we will show that no element of $G$ normalizes $B$ unless it is in ker $f$. Let $(f_1,n) \in G$. Then $(f_1,n)^{-1} = (x^{-n}f_1,-n)$. We just need to show that $(f_1,n)$ does not normalize $B$ if $n \neq 0$. Let $(g,0) \in B$ (so again, $g$ is a Laurent polynomial). We will specify later what $g$ will be.

We have $(f_1,n)(g,0)(x^{-n}f_1,-n) = (f_1 + x^ng,n)(x^{-n}f_1,-n)
= (f_1 + x^ng + f_1, 0) = (x^ng,0)$. Notice that if we take $g = x^{-n}$, then we have shown that $(f_1,n)$ conjugates $(g,0)$ to an element outside of $B$ (assuming $n\neq 0$). Therefore assuming $n\neq0$, we have shown that $(f_1,n) \notin N_G(B)$.

---

Final remark: Notice that in the above counterexample, ker $f$ is not finitely generated as a group. (Regardless, $G$ itself is finitely generated. In fact it is 2-generated.) I was led to the stated example because each of the other examples I tried where ker $f$ was finitely generated, I failed to produce a counterexample.